# How do I insert the current year in PowerPoint

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2010

I'd like to have the current year appear on the footer of my slides.

I've been doing this by manually typing the year, but every year, I need to update all my slides. Can I insert the year automatically, just like I can insert the date and have it update automatically?

Comment: Perhaps you can add an automatically updated date via the Insert tab, then hide the date and month using an opaque rectangle, leaving only the year? I don't know of any other way to specify a custom date format in PowerPoint, and VBA is an ugly solution for this (especially since you'd need a hack to make the PPT auto-execute the macro when the file is opened or slideshow is run).

Comment: @Karan: That was exactly the solution I first thought. But I still asked, as I assumed this would be a rather common need. Guess I'll have to hide the Month/Day.

Comment: I guess you mean you need to update all your _templates_? That's a lot less work than updating all your slides.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to format just the year in a PPT date footer.

This is a workaround. My use case is a copyright stamp in the lower right hand corner of each slide. I have one template with my house style. For new presentations, I edit the template. For existing presentations that you need to update, skip the first step.

1. For PTT 2010, your templates are in `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates`. '..\Templates' may be the word for Templates in your own language. YMMV, Microsoft tends to change its mind about the best place for these with various versions of PPT and Windows. Right click on the template and select Open. Don't doubleclick, you'll open a new blank document from the template. That's not what you want.
2. Click the View tab, select 'Master slides', or Microsofts' translation for it ('Diamodel' in Dutch), then click the Master slides tab. You have to go via View - Master slides to get to see this tab.
3. In the left pane, you see the master-master, slightly larger than other style masters below it. Click it.
4. Click anywhere on the slide in the main panel, go to the Insert tab and make a nice text box with your year in it. Place it where it doesn't sit in the way of anything else, like headers or footers. I'm not using any headers or footers, so I put mine in the lower right corner, partially overlapping with the default footer box for slide number.
5. If you did step 1, save your template and start a new presentation from it. (File -> new -> your bewdiful template.)

Next year, remember to check back here and repeat. I hope *I* will. Re-invented this wheel at least three times in the last few years.

Answer (score 0):

Easier than everyone is making it. Just insert date from the Insert tab on the ribbon use format with the year at the end like mm/dd/yyyy, then just highlight mm/dd/ and set font to one and font color to match your background color. mm/dd/ will disappear and the year will update per normal.

Answer (score 0):

I hope it's not too late, :). Try this:

1. Enable "Developer" tab;
2. Enable "Macros";
3. Insert "Label" at anywhere you like;
4. Click "Visual Basic" in Developer tab, enter the Visual Basic window;
5. Select Slide which was inserted the label;
6. Paste the code below (change the label name `label1` when needed):

   ```vb
   Sub OnSlideShowPageChange()
     If ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.CurrentShowPosition = 1 Then
         Label1.AutoSize = False
         Label1.Width = 33
         Label1.Height = 14
         Dim now_year As Integer
         now_year = Year(Date)
         Label1.BackColor = &HFFFFFF
         Label1.ForeColor = &H0
         Label1.BorderColor = &HFFFFFF
         Label1.Caption = now_year
     End If
   End Sub
   ```
7. Save and Run.

Comment: Personally I would have used `With Label1` so that there was only one place you needed to change in the code.

Answer (score -1):

Try this [answer](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/custom-date-format-t3129006.html). May be that will help you.  Here is another similar [answer](http://help.wugnet.com/office/date-formats-added-edited-PowerPoint-2007-ftopict1149279.html).

> You can get this change
>    system-wide through Windows Control Panel, launch "Regional and Language
>    Options", click "Customize this format...", select "Date" tab, and type out
>    "d.M.yy" in "Short date" area, click OK. This should get you 19.06.07 date
>    format in PowerPoint as well.

In your case you can try "yyyy" for your *short date*.

Comment: This doesn't really help me, as I will pass the document around and changing my whole OS date format is not something I'd like to do.